# How to verify dask is using multiple processors?

Tags: python, dask

Having `dask` installed I would like to verify that `dask` is indeed using multiple processors for computing something.

1. How to find out how many processors/nodes are available?
2. And what simple test code can I use to show that indeed multiple processors are used? A good example would be some code that (1) runs a standalone and (2) with dask using multiple processors, where I can measure the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

To know how many processors you have you can use `os.cpu_count()`. If you want to know how many workers, core and run you have you can use

```py
from distributed import Client
client = Client()
client
```

[image]

In order to see examples I suggest you to check these [tutorials](https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial) out.